# partial template specialization and deduction guides

Tags: c++

I have a question on when deduction guides need to be specified, in particular why explicitly defining the constructor in the base template below removes the requirement for it. IOW, either the constructor in the base template needs to be defined or the deduction guide is needed for the snippet below to compile. I'm guessing it relates to deduction of the base template parameter requiring the constructor but would appreciate the clarification here.

```cpp
#include <utility>
template <typename ...T>
struct Type {
   // Needs to be uncommented if deduction guide is not specified
   // Type(T&&...) { }
   
};

template <typename T, typename ...Ts>
struct Type<T, Ts...> : Type<Ts...> {
   Type(T&& x, Ts&&... y) : Type<Ts...>(std::forward<Ts>(y)...) {
   }
};

//template <typename ...T>
//Type(T&&...) -> Type<T...>;

int main() { 
   Type t{1,2.3,false};
}
```

Comment: Deduction guides are not in C++11.  I'll replace that tag with C++; if you have a specific version you want an answer for, also add it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class template argument deduction uses a set of implicit guides synthesized from the *primary* template definition, plus any explicit *deduction-guides* declared for the class template.

The partial specialization of `Type` does not participate in the generation of implicit guides. Nor would any explicit (full) specialization, if there were any in your program.

If you do not declare an explicit *deduction-guide*, then you must have an appropriate constructor in the **primary** class template in order for a similar guide to be generated implicitly.<sup>1</sup>

<sup>1</sup> There are some exceptions; certain guides are generated implicitly even in the absence of a constructor. I won't get into this here.

Comment: Oh thank you so much. I missed the fine point that a similar constructor must be present in the primary class template. This can be _a pitfall_ when the primary class template is an empty shell with a static_assert, and users are expected to provide partial specialisations...